# Is this the way to make a synchronous library function awaitable without creating a background thread?

Tags: c#, async-await

I need to take a 3rd party function that is I/O bound and convert it so it is awaitable without creating a background thread.  There are no native async methods for this call.

It is my understanding that this will work, but it will create a background thread every time it is called.

```
public string SomeSyncFunction()
{
  Threading.Sleep(5000);
  return "done";
}

//awaitable but creates a background thread
public Task<string> SomeSyncFunctionAsync()
{
  return Task.Run(() => SomeSyncFunction());
}
```

I believe this is the way to do it without a new thread, but not completely sure.

```
public Task<string> SomeSyncFunctionAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();   
    try
    {
        tcs.SetResult(SomeSyncFunction());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tcs.SetException(e);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't really make it asynchronous at all. Heck, you can do it simpler with `return Task.FromResult(SomeSyncFunction());` but it doesn't achieve asynchrony. What do you hope to achieve from making it awaitable?

Comment: I assume the goal is better responsiveness.

Comment: A background thread is the best you're going to be able to do if the underlying library is already making blocking calls (other than replacing the library).

Comment: Can your operation complete without the use of a thread? Do you have some way of being notified of its completion? If "yes" to both, then you can use `TaskCompletionSource`. But for it to be useful, you'd have to be able to return the `Task` object _before_ you have completed the operation. The code example you've got above doesn't return until you've already completed the operation, which is useless and doesn't make it asynchronous at all.

Comment: What you describe is "async over sync", and is not recommended

Comment: Marc Gravell can you explain why it is not recommended?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of "awaitability" is that some instructions are executed in background allowing your code to proceed further.

What do you mean "make synchronous function awaitable without a thread"? Synchronous function (as opposed to truly asynchronous functions that rely on hardware) needs CPU to run, so it needs a thread. Otherwise, if it is executed without new thread, then there is no point in "awaitablility" (it will block).
Btw if you're concerned about system resources, then .Net Task mechanism won't probably spawn new system threads but re-use the ones already created for Tasks.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to take a 3rd party function that is I/O bound and convert it so it is awaitable without creating a background thread. There are no native async methods for this call.

This is not possible, sorry.

Your best option is to contact the 3rd party and ask them for asynchronous APIs.

In the meantime, you'll either have to just keep the synchronous API calls (if your app is an ASP.NET app, or if the calling code is already on a non-UI thread), or wrap the synchronous API in a `Task.Run` (if it is called from a UI thread).